# Gnome - Laptop Monitor Off when Lid Closes?

Tags: gnome, laptop, monitors

I'm running Gnome (Wayland) on Arch Linux. I have configured the environment not to go to suspend, etc. when the lid is closed. When I close the lid, the monitor turns off for a second or two (as though it's responding to the laptop lid state changing), then turns back on. Likewise, when I open the lid, it turns off for a second or two, then turns back on. (If I wasn't careful, I might have thought the monitor was turning off when closing the lid...sneaky Gnome!)

How do I make it so that the computer stays on and responds to, e.g. network events, but the monitor doesn't stay on all day?

Comment: I don't use Gnome, but is something like `xset dpms force off` acceptable?

Comment: Wayland? One of the commands [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/linux4noobs/comments/5cg8ck/turning_off_the_display_in_gnome_in_wayland/d9wd31k/) might work.

Comment: From [freedesktop](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/writing-desktop-environments/): *If your session manager handles ... the laptop lid switch on its own it is welcome to do so, but needs to disable logind's built-in handling of these events.* So you might look for clues in the interaction of systemd-logind and gnome/wayland.

Comment: @Sparhawk Since I'm not running X, that doesn't work.

Comment: I'm not sure what happened to your comment, but was my link helpful?

Comment: @Sparhawk That second one seems to work well enough when I enter the command, but it sure would be nice for that to happen (automatically) when I close the lid. I always thought this was a hardware thing...

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstand. From you last sentence, I thought you were looking for a way to leave the computer open and on, but turn the screen off.

Comment: @Sparhawk Not *open* and on, just on (confer the question title) ;-) I SSH to it regularly and use it headless throughout the day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [gdm](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GDM). It handles this and many other things automatically.

Comment: Could you elaborate on that a bit? Maybe tell us where to set the options needed?

Comment: @Mioriin I didn't have to set up anything. `sudo pacman -Syu gdm; sudo systemctl enable gdm; sudo reboot;` That's it. That's why my answer has the word "automatically" :-)

Comment: NO. I am running gdm. It doesn't turn off the monitor. Your word "automatically" does NOT work.

Comment: Sorry, that was a while back. I don't use gdm anymore. Good luck out there!